# what is multiplicative group of all integers coprime with $N$ called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, finite-fields

what is multiplicative group of all integers coprime with $N$ called?

I am not sure the tags are correct or not!

Comment: I'm not sure it's called anything in particular. Do you remember seeing a name?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to me that the set of integers coprime with some number $N$ is not a group under multiplication in general as most elements are lacking inverses.

Comment: @IanColey No I don't. But I thought maybe it have name! Does it have a special notation?

Comment: Matthias is right; it would be a monoid.

Comment: I think what I am looking for is [Multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n)

Answer (score 4):

It's called the group of units mod n, often written $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

By the way, the superscript-cross notation commonly refers to the group of units in the ring, so this is an example of that notation.